# the flash adobe debugger version

Tags: apache-flex, flashbuilder4

please, i was previously able to debug my application in flash builder. but then, i upgraded to flash builder 4.5 and changed my sdk from 4.1 to 4.5 and flash player 10.0 to 10.2. that was when the problem started. i realised, the current flash builder 4.5 is not yet compatible with what i am currently working with so, i reverted to the default setting : flash player 10.0, sdk 4.1 and ran my programme, it worked fine except that i cannot debug anymore :( 
each time i try to debug, i get this :

```
"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin

Flash Builder cannot locate the required debugger version of Adobe Flash Player. You       
might need to install the debugger version of the Flash Player or reinstall Flash 
Builder.

Do you want to try to debug with the current version?"
```

I have reinstalled my flash builder and yet, i still get the same problem each time i try to debug :( it is getting frustrating, anyone ever come across this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a debug version of the player for your browser of choice.  Find it here:

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: i will try it out and let you know how it went.

Comment: Then be sure to accept this as the answer if it solved your problem.  there is a checkbox next to my answer that you need to click.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, all the Flash Player versions are rather backward compatible and you shouldn't reinstall Flash Player — it hasn't sense.

Second, I suppose the current version of Flash Player which installed in your browser is not a debug version but release one. You can make sure by opening some web page with Flash (for example YouTube) and perform right-click on a Flash Movie. If you hasn't `Debugger` line in a context menu you have a release version. In this case you should install debug version of Flash Player. You can find it in `{You Flash Builder Installation Root}/player` folder.

And the last thing, you shouldn't reinstall Flash Builder 4.5 to have older Flex SDK versions. It allows you to manage multiply SDKs. Just go to `Preferences>Flash Builder>Installed Flex SDKs` and add your 4.1 SDK location there. You can even set it as default and switch SDK on existing projects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i had FB 4 on my system and it was working correctly and debugging correctly until i decided to try out FB 4.5 so i changed the sdk to 4.5 and the flash player version to 10.2 but immediately realized that itz still a trial version and not compatible with what i was working with so i reverted back to sdk 4.1 and flash player version 10.0 and suddenly, i couldn't debug anymore :( i do not have a debug player and so i copied one from another location to the player folder but wont work still..i guess i have to download a new one.

Comment: hi, i did go to a youtube flash movie and righ clicked on it but i didnt get what else to check? what link to click when i right click is not clear

Comment: First of all it seems you're confused by terms Flash Builder and Flex SDK and their versions. SDK is just a set of binary utilities and libraries and Flash Builder is IDE. So you can use different SDKs from within your IDE (you can use SDKs 4.1 or 4.5 from Flash Builder 4.5 and all you 4.1 projects can be work fine without any changes).

Comment: The second thing is about Flash Player. You need to set up a proper Flash Player version to your browser. It is not copying but installing. You can read installation instructions [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/productinfo/instructions/).

Comment: What about determining what version of Flash Player (release or debug) do you have you should invoke context menu on any Flash movie within your primary browser. And read every context menu item (the menu where you can see About Flash Player item). The algorithm of determining is very simple. While looping by your eyes through every context menu items you're comparing them with "Debugger" word. If you're looped all the menu and didn't find "Debugger" word you have release version and should install debugger one.

Comment: hi Constantiner, that was what i did, and realized the version was 10.2 how it suddenly became 10.2, i don't know. so, i just downloaded the debugger for that version and the error was gone. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a capabilities class in flex that tells you straight up if you have a flash debugger or not..
just run this small code and check if you have it:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

private function reportVersion():String{
if(Capabilities.isDebugger)
return "you have a debugger";
else 
return "you don't have a debugger";
}

//
<mx:Label text ="{reportVersion()}"/>
```

if the return statement was "you don't have a debugger,

downlaod an uninstaller for your operating system from the link  :http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/192/tn_19254.html

and after uninstalling, try to install the right debugger ..from this
    link:http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

by the way, to check the adobe debugger version, you can run this simple code as well..

```
private function reportType():String{
return Capabilities.version;
}
```